# How to run query with parameters in DataGrip?

Tags: sql, jetbrains-ide, datagrip, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In DataGrip, how can I pass parameters to SQL query? Say I have a query:

```
select * from table where date >= ?
```

Then how can I bind the variable here? When I open the parameters pane, i.e. click the `P` button here.

[image]

I see

> No parameters present

Or:

[image]

Where should I set the parameter value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just run it via Ctrl+Enter! [image] The parameter pop-up will appear.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use pre-defined parameters to easily bind them into a query, more data can be found in this link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/settings-tools-database-user-parameters.html

i.e if you need to replace one variable in more than one place, do it with **:var_name**

And it will replace all its occurrences in the query.

Select x
from y
where z = (:val) and w = (:val)