# How to execute SELECT with params in DataGrip / PgAdmin etc..?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, datagrip

I need to execute a complex query for testing purposes with params.

How to write a SELECT query which can be executed in DataGrip / PgAdmin with params:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM tenant where id = $1'
   USING 6;
END
```

(this doesn't work)

and I need to get the same result as from:

```
SELECT * FROM tenant where id = 6
```

Thank you

Comment: Does it answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/54781984/8203759 ?

Comment: Variables can only be used inside e.g. a `DO` block - but a `DO` block can't return a result.

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov no it does not - I have more than 100 variables which I don't want to enter manually

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490942/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-postgresql-query

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution, even it's a bit tricky:

```
DO
$$
    DECLARE
        res RECORD;
    BEGIN
        drop table if exists my_temp_table;

        EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMP TABLE my_temp_table AS
        SELECT * FROM tenant where id = $1'
            USING 3243;

    END
$$;
select * from my_temp_table;
```